# Why might SO have been blocked at my work earlier?

Tags: discussion, filtering

I can normally get to SO just fine at work, but today at around 1530GMT I got the corporate "This page has been blocked" message. The reason given was "Weighted phrase limit exceeded", which usually means too many naughty words.

This was the main question index, at http://stackoverflow.com.

I've emailed the people responsible for the filter, but they would have gone home. Given the scary warning about disciplinary action, I wasn't about to try the page again later, either. Looking at it now, from home, I can't see anything that might trip the filter.

Did something happen on SO earlier that might have caused this (for example, someone spamming with rude questions)? If it helps, we use DansGuardian.

Comment: This isn't a Stack Overflow problem. Sorry. :(

Comment: There were recently two deleted questions named "Algo female behavior", by a user named "evil.coder". It's possible the words female and evil tripped your filter, but.... I dunno. Seems like a rather heavy-handed filter if that's what tripped it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, only your local network policy can tell you. When I was on the corporate LAN, I used to get occasional issues - but maybe that was because moderation involves snooping around (and killing) the very worst posts. I also wondered if one of the ads was upsetting it, as refreshing would sometimes fix it.